# Use of 'internal' not working when distributing Swift project through Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swift4

I'm distributing a framework through cocoapods in which I'm making use of another small library that has made some extensions on common Classes like `Date`, and is also using common namespace, claiming `.week`, `.day`, etc.

I've copied the files used in the framework over and have declared all variable declarations as `internal`.

However still, some of my clients are getting errors like "Ambiguous use of 'week'" when using it along with the common date frameworks.

Am I wrong to assume that `internal` will only be shared with the files inside of the project itself? Or should I do something different entirely?

**Code Example**

```
internal extension Int {
    internal var nanosecond: DateComponents { return nanoseconds }
    internal var second: DateComponents { return seconds }
    internal var minute: DateComponents { return minutes }
    internal var hour: DateComponents { return hours }
    internal var day: DateComponents { return days }
    internal var week: DateComponents { return weeks }
    internal var month: DateComponents { return months }
    internal var year: DateComponents { return years }
}
```

The above extension is visible for anyone downloading this code through cocoapods.

Comment: It would help to show a clear example of code causing the issue.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for the suggestion, please let me know if this helps to understand the question better

Answer (score 0):

`internal` mean the property only available to use inside the module, this case is your cocoapods module for that library, so you cant see or use it on the app codebase, make it `public` or `open` then your client can use them in their app project.

More info can be found in [Swift docs for access control](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html)

Comment: Hi Tj3n, the problem is that this interface should *not* be visible outside the module because it is causing name collision within people's project.

Comment: Probably the client trying to use it with your framework thus the error that said it shouldn't be visible, I think the best way is to add your own namespace to the variable, I also have to do it for my Obj-C framework to prevent collision